# Mapping a Lower triangular matrix into a 1D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, data-structures

I'm aware of the math and logic behind. I'm just curious if there's any better implementation of this since my functions have the time complexity of O(n<sup>2</sup>) because of iterations on the matrix's shape, and that's probably not the best implementation.

Here are my functions:

```py
def Row_major_mapper(arr : np.ndarray, n : int) -> np.ndarray : 
    arr = np.zeros((int(n * (n+1) / 2),))
    
    for i in range(mat.shape[0]) :
        for j in range(mat.shape[1]) : 
            if i < j : 
                continue
            else : 
                k = int(((i+1)*(i)/2) + (j))
                arr[k] = mat[i, j]

    return arr


def Column_major_mapper(arr : np.ndarray, n : int) -> np.ndarray : 
    arr = np.zeros((int(n * (n+1) / 2),))
    
    for i in range(mat.shape[0]) : 
        for j in range(mat.shape[1]) : 
            if i < j : 
                continue
            else :
                k = int(
                    n * j - ((j-1) * (j) / 2) + i - j 
                )
                arr[k] = mat[i, j]
    return arr
```

Yes, i'm using numpy since python doesn't support static or 2D arrays itself and i don't wanna use the specific builtin functions of numpy for it (like boolean masking for finding non-zero elements)

I'm tryin to create the functions with bare minimums as much as possible. If you couldn't guess, i'm taking a "Data Structure and Algorithms" course. that's the reason behind not using so many builtin functions.

My main point here is about **efficiency and reducing the time complexity**.

Comment: Because a matrix is a square structure, you cannot do better than O(n^2) where n is the length or width of the matrix. What you can do is prune some branches. For example, `j` is being incremented, so when `i < j` the first time, `i` will always be less than `j` for the entire run of the inner loop, so you can `break` instead of `continue` at that point.

Comment: Using `ndarray` iteratively like this is inefficient.  Don't treat an array as though it were a list of lists.  Stick with lists for that.  If using numpy arrays, use their builtin methods, otherwise you can forget about efficiency.

Comment: @hpaulj so what you're saying, is that i'm using numpy just for 2D arrays, then it would be more straight forward to just create 2D arrays by list of lists? Am i getting you right?

Comment: For the first function it should be possible to remove the inner loop by setting `k = int(((i+1)*(i)/2))` and then `arr[k:(k + i + 1)] = mat[i, 0:(i + 1)]`

Comment: Based on the size of the inputs, `numba` would be very helpful to accelerate the code performance without changing the code, if you could use it for jitting.

Answer (score 1):

Let's explore some alternatives; start with a simple 4x4 array

```
In [193]: mat = np.arange(16).reshape(4,4); mat
Out[193]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15]])
```

Your function:

```
In [194]: Row_major_mapper(mat,4)
Out[194]: array([ 0.,  4.,  5.,  8.,  9., 10., 12., 13., 14., 15.])
```

Essentially the same thing, but using list append.  Lists are designed for efficient appending, so this pattern is widely used (don't try to imitate it with `np.append`):

```
In [195]: alist=[]
     ...: for i in range(4):
     ...:     for j in range(4):
     ...:         if j>i: continue
     ...:         else:
     ...:             alist.append(mat[i,j])
     ...: alist
Out[195]: [0, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15]
```

While this requires full iteration on all 16 elements, the action for the upper tri is simpler, and this expected to be slightly faster.

We can refine that by using `break` instead of `continue`, skipping further iterations on `j` (for the current `i`):

```
In [196]: alist=[]
     ...: for i in range(4):
     ...:     for j in range(4):
     ...:         if j>i: break
     ...:         else:
     ...:             alist.append(mat[i,j])
     ...: alist
Out[196]: [0, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15]
```

And as a further refinement, incorporate that `break` into the `range` generator:

```
In [197]: alist=[]
     ...: for i in range(4):
     ...:     for j in range(i+1):
     ...:         alist.append(mat[i,j])
     ...: alist
Out[197]: [0, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15]
```

`numpy` has some functions to working with upper/lower triangles.

For example, the lower triangle, with the upper values all set to 0:

```
In [198]: np.tril(mat)
Out[198]: 
array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 4,  5,  0,  0],
       [ 8,  9, 10,  0],
       [12, 13, 14, 15]])
```

The indices for those lower values:

```
In [199]: np.tril_indices_from(mat)
Out[199]: (array([0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]), array([0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3]))
```

And using those indices to select the values from `mat`:

```
In [200]: mat[np.tril_indices_from(mat)]
Out[200]: array([ 0,  4,  5,  8,  9, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15])
```

Under the covers (in python code) the `tril` functions make heavy use of `arange` comparisons:

For example `broadcasting` `[0,1,2,3]` against `[[1],[2],[3],[4]]` yields this 4x4 boolean array (mask):

```
In [202]: np.arange(4)<(np.arange(4)[:,None]+1)
Out[202]: 
array([[ True, False, False, False],
       [ True,  True, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True, False],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True]])
```

and the `nonzero` indices of these `True` values is [199]:

```
In [203]: np.nonzero(np.arange(4)<(np.arange(4)[:,None]+1))
Out[203]: 
(array([0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3], dtype=int64),
 array([0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3], dtype=int64))
```

That [202] boolean array can be used directly to select elements from `mat` (without the `nonzero` step):

```
In [213]: mat[np.arange(4)<np.arange(4)[:,None]+1]
Out[213]: array([ 0,  4,  5,  8,  9, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15])
```

Evaluating the relative time complexity of these `numpy` versions is tricky, because they mix python and compiled numpy methods.  Further more, for small sizes, the list based python is usually faster, while the numpy code scales much better.

Speaking of mixing python and numpy, maybe I should have used nested list equivalent of `mat`:

```
In [205]: mmat = mat.tolist(); mmat
Out[205]: [[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14, 15]]

In [206]: alist=[]
     ...: for i in range(4):
     ...:     for j in range(i+1):
     ...:         alist.append(mmat[i][j])
     ...: alist
Out[206]: [0, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15]
```

Note I had to change the indexing of the nest list.  The `[i,j]` format works for arrays, but not for lists.

Speaking of mixing python and numpy, a comment suggested taking a slices of the `mat[i]` row:

```
In [208]: alist=[]
     ...: for i in range(4):
     ...:     alist.append(mat[i,:i+1])
     ...: alist
Out[208]: [array([0]), array([4, 5]), array([ 8,  9, 10]), array([12, 13, 14, 15])]
```

or using the `extend` to flatten the append:

```
In [209]: alist=[]
     ...: for i in range(4):
     ...:     alist.extend(mat[i,:i+1])
     ...: alist
Out[209]: [0, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15]
```

Instead of iterating on the range, we can iterate on the rows directly - though I still need to get the row index via `enumerate`:

```
In [210]: alist=[]
     ...: for i, row in enumerate(mmat):
     ...:     alist.extend(row[:i+1])
     ...: alist
Out[210]: [0, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15]
```

This alternative is more of a stylistic choice than any sort of efficiency or complied issue.

The `O` complexity of the `numpy` calculations is much higher.  The [202] mask requires iterting on the rows and the columns.  And again applying to index `mat` requires the same pair of iterations.  But since those are done in compiled code, they are (potentially) faster that the pure python level iterations.

Answer (score 0):

There are two answers to this question - a theoretical answer and a practical answer.

The theoretical answer is that an O(n^2) program is already optimal. If you have an NxN matrix, and you want the lower triangle, then you need to copy at least O((n^2 + n) / 2)) elements. Since O((n^2 + n) / 2)) is within a constant factor of O(n^2), it is not possible to have a complexity faster than O(n^2). You can only do better by a constant factor.

The practical answer is - sometimes constant factors matter! You can do this computation entirely in NumPy, and that is usually* faster.

Here's how to use [triangular indicies](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tril_indices.html) to solve this.

```py
def row_major_mapper_np(mat):
    return mat[np.tril_indices_from(mat)]
def column_major_mapper_np(mat):
    return mat[tuple(reversed(np.triu_indices_from(arr)))]
```

*Note: Benchmarking shows that your Python solution is actually faster than the NumPy solution for matrices smaller than 10x10. For sufficiently large matricies that are 100x100 to 1000x1000, the NumPy approach is about 50-100x faster than the Python approach.